# using variable in a url in python

Tags: python

Sorry for this very basic question. I am new to Python and trying to write a script which can print the URL links. The IP addresses are stored in a file named list.txt. How should I use the variable in the link? Could you please help?

```
# cat list.txt

192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.9
```

script:

```
import sys
import os

file = open('/home/list.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    source = line.strip('\n')
    print source

link = "https://(source)/result”
print link
```

output:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.9
https://(source)/result
```

Expected output:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.9
https://192.168.0.1/result
https://192.168.0.2/result
https://192.168.0.9/result
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the actual variable, you can iterate over the file object so you don't need to use readlines and use `with` to open your files as it will close them automatically. You also need the print inside the loop if you want to see each line and `str.rstrip()` will remove any newlines from the end of each line:

```
with open('/home/list.txt') as f:  
    for ip in f:
        print "https://{0}/result".format(ip.rstrip())
```

If you want to store all the links use a [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php):

```
with  open('/home/list.txt' as f:
    links = ["https://{0}/result".format(ip.rstrip()) for line in f]
```

For python 2.6 you have to pass the *numeric index of a positional argument,* i.e `{0}` using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) .

You can also use names to pass  to str.format:

```
with open('/home/list.txt') as f:
    for ip in f:
        print "https://{ip}/result".format(ip=ip.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic.. tried but getting this error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 7, in <module>
    links = ["https://{}/result".format(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @user3331975, try it now, you are using python < 2.7 yes?

Comment: @user3331975, for python > 2.6 you don't need to pass the positional indexes to str.format

Answer (score 3):

Get the link inside the loop, you are not appending data to it, you are assigning to it every time. Use something like this:

```
file = open('/home/list.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    source = line.strip('\n')
    print source
    link = "https://%s/result" %(source)
    print link
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in file]

for source in lines:
    print source

for source in lines:
    link = "https://{}/result".format(source)
    print link
```

The feature you just described is often called [string interpolation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/String_interpolation).
In Python, this is called [string formatting](http://pyformat.info/).

There are two styles of string formatting in Python: the old style and the new style.
What I've shown in the example above is the new style, in which we format with a string method named `format`.
While the old style uses the `%` operator, eg. `"https://%s/result" % source`

Answer (score 2):

Use format specifier for string and also put the link printing section in the for loop only
something like this:

```
import sys
import os
    file = open('/home/list.txt', 'r')
    for line in file.readlines():
        source = line.strip('\n')
        print source
        link = "https://%s/result”%source
        print link
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import os

file = open('/home/list.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    source = line.strip('\n')
    print source
    link = "https://" + str(source) + "/result”
    print link
```